# python : the selenium webscraping script not working through module

Tags: python, selenium

whenever I am running the following script through shell its working but whenever i am running the same script through python module or pycharm its not working, its not fetching the data. Can anyone please help in that ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
site = browser.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
searchInput = browser.find_element_by_class_name("LM6RPg")
searchInput.send_keys('Laptop')
searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
titleResults = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']")
for title in titleResults:
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `implicitly_wait` after `browser = webdriver.Firefox()` because when you run in shell the page will have time to load completely and when you run it like a module you are not waiting for the page to load at all so it should be:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

This will wait for a maximum of 10 seconds to find the element before an exception will be thrown.

Alternatives are:

```
browser.explicitly_wait(10)
```

which will wait 10 seconds and after that it will search the element

or

```
sleep(5)
```

before searching for element after clicking a button. You can adjust the the seconds to see which fits. And don't forget to import `sleep` from `time` module : `from time import sleep`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, however, there are still some flaws with the code its not fetching all the result, in the actual website there are 18 results in the first page, however when i am running the script its only getting 10 results out of 18, class names are same for all the items in the webpage.Could you please help me with that too ?

Comment: Yes, I've tested myself and I think that not every product is loaded when you search for them and I have waited for 5 seconds after searching for "Laptop" and I've found 18 products, so at the beggining of the file put `from time import sleep` and after `searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` put `sleep(5)` and it will work. Please accept my answer if it's working now.

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept my answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
    from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
    caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    caps["marionette"] = True
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe")

    site = browser.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
    searchInput = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='LM6RPg']")
    searchInput.send_keys('Laptop')
    searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='container']//div[text()='Dell Inspiron Core i3 6th Gen - (4 GB/1 TB HDD/Windows 10 Home) 3467 Notebook']")))
    titleResults = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3wU53n']")
    for title in titleResults:
        print(title.text)
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i added browser.implicitly_wait in my script it and now its working fine, one more favour, could you please suggest me any book or any site to learn more about webdriver and selenium ?

Comment: @sandipghoshal ImplicitlyWait may appear simple to implement but as per Jim & recent Austin Selenium Conference ImplicitlyWait may be deprecated in Selenium 4.0. Hence my solution was based on ExplicitlyWait. Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks